# IsMouseOver doesnt work after item deselect

Tags: wpf

I have an issue where the deselected item in my listview doesnt show the color of "IsMouseOver" after I deselect it unless I select something else and then select it. In my ItemContainerStyle I've set the default color of focus/unfocus to transparent because I want to define my own values. Can anyone look at this and tell me why "IsMouseOver" doesnt work on the deselected item?

xaml:

```
<ListView Name="lstPhoneCarrier" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="408" Height="145" 
  ItemsSource="{Binding ShowAllCarrierInfo, Mode=TwoWay}" 
  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
  SelectionMode="Single">

<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
        </Style.Resources>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Label x:Name="lblCarrier" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Label.Content>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock.Text>
                            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}-{1}">
                                <Binding Path="Name" />
                                <Binding Path="Description" />
                             </MultiBinding>
                        </TextBlock.Text>
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Label.Content>
        </Label>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CarrierSelected}" Value="True" >
                <Setter TargetName="lblCarrier" Property="Background" Value="Pink" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have override the highlight brush so that selection is not visible to user but internally `selection` is still working which `captures the mouse` and hence `MouseOver events not getting raised for that item`.

You need to set `Focusable` to `false` for `listBoxItem` so that mouse didn't get capture in `ItemContainerStyle` -

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
         <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/> // <---- HERE
        <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" 
                             Color="Transparent" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}"
                             Color="Transparent" />
        </Style.Resources>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: By adding what you suggested, the property for SelectedItem is not working.

Comment: Yeah, that's what i mentioned since item is selected hence mouse over events won't be raised. So, for that you have to make the item non-focusable. That means it's kind of tradeoff between selection and mouse over.